# Finding limits of multiple functions

Tags: calculus, limits

I just wanted to confirm that the answers to the question are:

a. 4

b. 1

c. -1/4

d. -37/13

[image]

If I am wrong, your advice  would be greatly appreciated

Also for finding limits in general. Is it ok to sub the value x is approaching to find the limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, all your answers are correct except for "d". It should be $f(3)=-\frac{37}{4}+3^2=-\frac{1}{4}$. Can't you see from the graph that the functions are glued together at the point $x=3$ which means their functional values must be the same at that point? Though, strictly speaking, $\frac{1}{-1-x}$ is not defined at $x=3$. Still, that's the point it's going to as you move along the x-axis to the right.

In this case, it is perfectly okay to plug the values x is approaching directly into the functions because all of them are continuous functions on their domains. That's usually the way you do these sorts of problems. The thing that's important here is that you understand why you're allowed to do that.

Comment: OP's answer of -37/13 probably comes from misinterpretting the function. OP probably saw $\frac{-37}{4 + x^2}$ instead of $\frac{-37}{4} + x^2$, though those have obviously different graphs.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. That might very well have been the case.

Comment: Yes, spot on Michael. That was the case.